# ForeignKey vs CharField

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-models

I have an idea for data model in django and I was wondering if someone can point out pros and cons for these two setups.

**Setup 1**: This would be an obvious one. Using CharFields for each field of each object

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    surname = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

**Setup 2**: This is the one I am thinking about. Using a ForeignKey to Objects that contain the values that current Object should have.

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.ForeignKey('Name')
    surname = models.ForeignKey('Surname')
    city = models.ForeignKey('City')

class Chars(models.Model):
    value = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.value

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class Name(Chars):pass
class Surname(Chars):pass
class City(Chars):pass
```

So in **setup 1**, I would create an Object with:

`Person.objects.create(name='Name', surname='Surname', city='City')`

and each object would have it's own data. In **setup 2**, I would have to do this:

```
_name = Name.objects.get_or_create(value='Name')[0]
_surname = Surname.objects.get_or_create(value='Surname')[0]
_city = City.objects.get_or_create(value='City')[0]
Person.objects.create(name=_name, surname=_surname, city=_city)
```

Question: Main purpose for this would be to reuse existing values for multiple objects, but is this something worth doing, when you take into consideration that you need multiple hits on the database to create an Object?

Comment: I would prefer 3rd setup: gender is an integer field (or boolean if you are more conservative person : ) and there is enum defined somewhere in django code.

Comment: Yea, it makes no difference what the variable is... I'll change it to city to avoid confusion

Answer (score 0):

Choosing the correct design pattern for your application is a very wide area which is influenced by many factors that are even possibly out of scope in a Stack Overflow question. So in a sense your question could be a bit subjective and too broad.

Nevertheless, I would say that assigning a separate model (class) for first name, another separate for last name etc. is an overkill. You might essentially end up overengineering your app.

The main reasoning behind the above recommendation is that you probably do not want to treat a name as a separate entity and possibly attach additional properties to it. Unless you really would need such a feature, a name is usually a plain string that some users happen to have identical.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't make any good to keep name and surname as separate object/model/db table. In your setup, if you don't set name and surname as unique, then it doesn't make any sense to put them in separate model. Even worse, it will incur additional DB work and decrease performance. Now, if you set them as unique, then you have to work over the situation when, e.g. some user changes his name and by default it would be changed for all users with that name.

On the other hand, city - there're not that many cities and it's a good idea to keep it as separate object and refer to it via foreign key from user. This will save disk space, allow to easily get all users from same city. Even better, you can prepopulate cities DB and provide autocompletion fro users entering there city. Though for performance you might still want to keep city as a string on the user model.

Also, to mention 'gender' field, since there're not many possible choices for this data, it's worth to use enumeration in your code and store a value in DB, i.e. use `choices` instead of `ForeignKey` to a separate DB table.